# How to get the last value in a table in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out, and even though I looked at several sites, I couldn't get this to work, and I know it's probably dead simple.

Using Power BI Desktop (September 2023), I'm trying to get a value from the last row of a table.

My source is a basic Excel with one table inside, three columns, first a Date, then two columns with numerical values:

| Date | OK | NOK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17/01/2024 | 123 | 2 |
| 18/01/2024 | 234 | 6 |
| 19/01/2024 | 56 | 9 |
| 20/01/2024 | 1 | 11 |
| 21/01/2024 | 23 | 34 |
| 22/01/2024 | 54 | 23 |

[image: image of basic Excel table]

In the Power Query Editor, I see that the date column is automatically recognized. To make sure the order is the one I want I force Sort by Date ascending.

[image: screenshot of power query editor]

I then display a table view of my data, as well as a card with the latest value from the NOK column. For this I created a new Measure, `Last NOK` that is defined like so:

`Last NOK = LASTNONBLANK(Table1[NOK], Table1[NOK])`. I've also tried `Last NOK = LASTNONBLANK(Table1[NOK], 1)` which should be equivalent in my case.

I hope you agree that I should see the value `23` displayed in the card on the next screenshot. I have no idea why it shows `9` instead. I had tried this with some more real-life data earlier, and there too, a value from somewhere inside the column was selected (always the same).

[image: screenshot of my test report]

I had found [this page](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/lastnonblank-explained/) which seemed to take the black magic out of this function, but still I must be doing something very simple very wrong. ‍♀️

Just to push the question a bit further I created equivalent measures for the other two columns:

[image: screenshot of overall data]

I should see 23, 54, and 22/01/2024, but only the date value is correct. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please paste your tables in markdown format next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power query doesn't affect the sorting in Power BI. The measure you want is:

```
Measure = LASTNONBLANKVALUE(Table1[Date], SUM(Table1[NOK]))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @davide, could add some explanation why this works and mine not? eager to finally grok this!

Comment: As I said, Power Query doesn't affect how tables are sorted in Power BI. You are using LASTNONBLANK() and I am using LASTNONBLANKVALUE - that is the only difference. You can read about the function here: https://dax.guide/lastnonblankvalue/. Please mark as solved and upvote if you found the answer helpful.

Comment: Would you know why I got the "wrong" values 9  and 56, but the "correct" date in my query? Thanks.

Comment: I can't recreate your results. For instance LASTNONBLANK(Table1[NOK], Table1[NOK]) gives me 34 which is correct in that context. You must be doing something else not revealed in your question.

Comment: Well I found that my numerical values were considered strings. So I added that "Change Type" action, and it now returns the expected values.